# Is it possible to close questions because they are already solved?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

Some questions happen to be solved for some reason (for instance, a new software version), and there's no answer it should be marked as accepted, but the question is not 'Open' anymore. And I don't think the question should be deleted because other users may have the same problem.

What's the best way to deal with this situation?

At least for me, it doesn't show up any option/action that would fit this situation on this question for instance: [sbt-codacy-coverage fails to upload data from Travis CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204252/sbt-codacy-coverage-fails-to-upload-data-from-travis-ci)

Comment: Wouldn't off-topic - Typo/no longer reproduceable work? It says: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: where are you reading that description? At least on SO it appears 'off topic - This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.'

Comment: It is a sub reason under off-topic, at least for me, but I'm above 3k so that might give me more options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If upgrading to a new version fixes the problem, then that can be the answer. No need to close or delete it, because it can be helpful for other people experiencing the same problem.

The answer doesn't have to be long, just say what version to upgrade to, give some context for the bug, and if possible link to the project's bug tracker. The comment you posted on the question has pretty much all that's needed for the answer.

Relevant discussions on MSO:

- [Are bug report-ish questions in the scope of SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308010/are-bug-report-ish-questions-in-the-scope-of-so)
- [Are questions about bugs on topic (when no code is presented)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318619/are-questions-about-bugs-on-topic-when-no-code-is-presented)

Answer (score 1):

Following scenarios may create the situation you described:

### 1. The OP got an answer

In such case, the OP should [post an answer to the own Qn](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Refer below related posts:

- [Is it ok to answer your own question and accept it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16930/163449)
- [Should I not answer my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12513/163449)
- [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/163449)

### 2a. The new software version automatically fixes the Qn

This seems to be your case.
In such case, a short answer is good enough. But if you wish to avoid answering it, then you may put it as an "**Update**" in the question itself. Depending on the context, these **Update** should be put in beginning or end with better visibility.

### 2b. The Qn is no more valid

This is rare. In such case Qn should not be deleted, if it *was* valid at some point of time. For more information, refer:

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/163449)